# How to write JPA Hibernate entity with three composite primary key and one foreign key?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am creating DB entities using JPA 2.0. My DB is PostGreSQL. Entities are as below:3

## ParentEntity

1. primary_key_1_long
2. primary_key_2_varchar
3. primary_key_3_varrchar
4. other_parent_columns

So, basically above entity has composite primary keys which includes - primary_key_1_long, primary_key_2_varchar, and primary_key_3_varchar.

## ChildEntity

1. primary_key_1_Long_ref
2. other_child_columns

The relationship between the two table is one-to-one. "primary_key_1_long" is used as foreign key to link parent table 'ParentEntity' with 'ChildEntity'.

**My approach:**

1. Using "Embedded" annotation I created java class which contains composite primary keys : primary_key_1_long, primary_key_2_varchar, and primary_key_3_varchar.
2. Using JPA entity @entity annotation I created entities 'ParentEntity" and 'ChildEntity".
3. I used instance of embedded class in both entities.

Problem:

1. Why primary keys of ParentEntity getting added in ChildEntity?
2. Is it mandatory that you have same set of primary keys from parent class present in child class too?

Can you please give me source code of this solution please? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Since merely asking for source code is not entertained at SO!

Comment: I tried what I write above. Read mr approach.

Comment: I'm asking for the source code perspective. Did you try writing the same?

Comment: Yes I wanted to give the source code here but it’s in my office laptop. I will cut and paste here for the sake of you.